# Working with large rasters using rioxarray

Tags: python, raster, python-xarray, rasterio

I am trying to re-write some of my R code in Python for doing raster reclassification on large rasters in a memory-safe way.

In R I would write the below. Because I have provided a filename argument to the classify line, this will work for large rasters and write the results to a file. No memory worries.

```
library("terra")
my_rast <- rast("my_rast.tif")
classify(my_rast, cbind(1, 10), filename = "reclassed_rast.tif")
```

I have read that rioxarray is good for raster processing in Python. So I have written the below code. But it crashes my memory. How do I fix that?

```
import rioxarray
my_rast = rioxarray.open_rasterio("my_rast.tif", cache=False, chunks = "auto")
my_rast_reclass = my_rast.where(my_rast != 1, 10)
my_rast_reclass.rio.to_raster("reclassed_rast.tif")
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify smaller chunks? Auto will use the chunking scheme within the file, which for rasters is one chunk for the whole thing

Comment: It's not the reading part of the file that is crashing, it's the 'where' line. Will the chunking still help? I'll try on Monday either way.

Comment: But when you call open_rasterio it does not read the file - it opens it for reading. The data is read when you require the data with the `where` line. So yes I’d try the chunking

Comment: I set chunks to 250, and it seems to work! Thanks. Just doing some more tests on larger files.